# React Navigation is not working in an axios call in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate the user towards home screen but my navigation is not working. Its showing alert of login successful but not navigating towards home screen here is my code...

```
 axios.post('/api_workreap/wp-json/api/v1/user/do_login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.type));
            if(response.data.type == "success"){
              alert("Login Successfully");
              // this.props.navigation.navigate("/src/Home/home.js");
              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'home' })
            }else if(response.data.type == "error"){
              alert("Incorrect Detail");
            }
        })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log( JSON.stringify(response));
          });
```

Comment: what navigation are you using?

Comment: react-navigation

Answer (score 2):

you can try [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), basically create your own navigation service on top of your navigation router, tutorial is pretty straight forward.